# MongoDB: Find Two Exact Matches In An Array But Not Either

Tags: mongodb

I've been battling with this for a while now and I can't seem to figure out how to perform what should theoretically be a pretty simple query...

I need to retrieve (or rather, exclude), documents that contain an array where two values are both present at an exact index in the array, but not where only one of them occurs at that exact index. I have tried the $and operator to achieve this, but I'm not getting the results I expect.

The array can also be longer than 2 values.

I have tried the following code, but all documents that contain either value in the exact position are omitted, and not only both.

```
$and: [{"value.0": {$ne: 'X'}}, {"value.1": {$ne: 'X'}}]
```

I would expect:

`[X,X]` to be excluded

`[Y,X]` to be included

`[X,Y]` to be included

Comment: Two values present at an exact index, what does that mean?? Both at index 'i'? How is that possible, please explain your problem more clearly

Comment: Can you put up your DB document here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tricky yes, but what you mean here is [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).

Take your documents:

```
{ "value" : [ "X", "X" ] }
{ "value" : [ "X", "X", "A" ] }
{ "value" : [ "Y", "X" ] }
{ "value" : [ "X", "Y" ] }
{ "value" : [ "B", "Y" ] }
```

And then run your [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) inequality conditions with an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```
db.collection.find({ 
  "$or": [
    { "value.0": { "$ne": "X" } },
    { "value.1": { "$ne": "X" } }
  ]
})
```

Returns the three documents:

```
{ "value" : [ "Y", "X" ] }
{ "value" : [ "X", "Y" ] }
{ "value" : [ "B", "Y" ] }
```

This is because **either** of the conditions needed to be complete, i.e `"X"` had to NOT be the value of **either** element in those positions. When your logic is *"either this **or** that"* then you actually mean [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).

Noting this should not be confused with [`$nor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) which is instead a statement that **none of the predicates** should match *"at all"*:

```
db.collection.find({ 
  "$nor": [
    { "value.0": "X" },
    { "value.1": "X" }
  ]
})
```

Would return:

```
{ "value" : [ "B", "Y" ] }
```

Which is **neither** of the positional values contain an `"X"`.

Basically comes down to the distinction between **either** and **neither** in what you need to apply

---

### Caveat

If what you are actually trying to ensure though is that the *"first to positions"* must contain an "X" in one of the elements, then you basically need a calculated expression to "slice" the array content added to the end of the query logic:

Either with modern MongoDB from 3.6 and upwards using [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) and [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)

```
db.collection.find({ 
  "$or": [
    { "value.0": { "$ne": "X" } },
    { "value.1": { "$ne": "X" } }
  ],
  "$expr": {
    "$in": [ "X", { "$slice": [ "$value", 0, 2 ] }]
  }
})
```

Or via [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) for older versions:

```
db.collection.find({ 
  "$or": [
    { "value.0": { "$ne": "X" } },
    { "value.1": { "$ne": "X" } }
  ],
  "$where": function() {
    return this.value.slice(0,2).indexOf("X") != -1
  }
})
```

Would both return only where `"X"` was present at all:

```
{ "value" : [ "Y", "X" ] }
{ "value" : [ "X", "Y" ] }
```

That additional logic to look at the "slice of an array" for a value to be present cannot be expressed with the regular query operators. So the *additional* statement is used in order discard anything with any "X" at all in those positions.

Note that *"technically"* the expressions there are all that is required, however such computed expressions require a collection scan, where the regular *inequality* operations actually do not.

Therefore it's better to combine the two if that was your intent.

Also *"technically"* simply matching `"X"` *"might"* suffice:

```
db.collection.find({ 
  "value": "X",
  "$or": [
    { "value.0": { "$ne": "X" } },
    { "value.1": { "$ne": "X" } }
  ]
})
```

But it's not a *guarantee* that the value is present in the *first two positions*.

Comment: Works a treat. Switching the $and to an $or made the difference. Can't believe I didn't try that.. Thanks for solving this!